# Неправильно работает привязка свойств PictureBox и моего класса

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

Работаю над прогой на WinForms.

Суть работы в следующем:

1. Открываю картинку или несколько
2. Выбираю картинку из списка **filesListBox**
3. Выделяю фрагмент на картинке **originalPicBox** прямоугольником
4. Выделенный фрагмент отрисовывается в отдельном **fragmentPicBox**е
5. По нажатию кнопки на форме происходит распознавание текста на картинке и вывод текста в **recognRichTBox**

Использую привязки объекта **PlotResult** к контролам формы чтобы обновлять состояние объекта.

```
public class PlotResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Image _originalImg;
    private Image _cropImg;
    private string _recognizedText;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Image OriginalImg {
        get 
        {
            return _originalImg;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (value != _originalImg)
            {
                _originalImg = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public Image CropImg {
        get 
        {
            return _cropImg;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _cropImg)
            {
                _cropImg = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Объекты храняться в коллекции

```
  BindingList<PlotResult> plotResults = new BindingList<PlotResult>();
```

Код формы с привязками

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        //Data bindings
        filesListBox.DataSource = plotResults;
        originalPicBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", plotResults, "OriginalImg", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        fragmentPicBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", plotResults, "CropImg", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
        recognRichTBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", plotResults, "RecognizedText", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    }
```

Прямоугольник выбора отрисовывается при движении мыши с нажатой ЛКМ. Картинка фрагмента вырезается при событии **MouseUp**, полный код

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureLoaded && selecting)
        {
            Image cropImg = null;
            selecting = false;
            mouseDown = false;
            
            Bitmap originalPic = (Bitmap)originalPicBox.Image;
            try
            {
                cropImg = originalPic.Clone(crop, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
                fragmentPicBox.Image = cropImg;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Какая-то обработка исключения
            }
        }
    }
```

Проблема в следующем: если пройти по алгоритму, как я указал выше, текст распознается, но картинка вырезанного фрагмента исчезает после добавления текста в **recognRichTBox**. Если после выделения прямоугольником перейти на другую картинку, а потом вернувшись запустить распознавание, все работает как нужно.

Код метода распознавания не привожу, т.к. проблема КМК именно в **MouseUp ивенте**. Картинка не записывается в свойство **CropImg**. Пробовал там же писать рандомный текст в **recognRichTBox** - текст записывается, а картинка нет и исчезает из **fragmentPicBox**.
Несколько раз переписывал и привязки и что только можно, в итоге окончательно запутался.

**UPD** код кнопки распознавания

```
private void recognizeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fragmentPicBox.Image == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Не выбран фрагмент файла");
            }
            else
            {
                Recognizer recognizer = new Recognizer(@"путь к файлу с моделью");
                if (region != Rectangle.Empty)
                {
                    (string recognizedText, bool succed) = recognizer.RecognizeIt((Bitmap)fragmentPicBox.Image);

                    if (succed)
                    {
                        toolStripProgressBar.PerformStep();
                    }
                    recognRichTBox.Text = recognizedText;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Какая-то обработка исключения
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вот просто сразу респект и плюс за INPC в Winforms. :)

Comment: `Код метода распознавания не привожу, т.к. проблема КМК именно в MouseUp ивенте` в MouseUp ивенте проблемы нет, покажите код распознавания и где он вызывается. Ведь если вы закомментируете вызов распознавания - картинка перестанет исчезать, так?

Comment: Заметил еще одну странность: добавил событие **ListChanged** коллекции для отладки. После выбора фрагмента изображения прямоугольником оно не срабатывает, хотя по идее должно, т.к. происходит установка свойства **fragmentPicBox.Image** контрола.
@aepot Добавил код кнопки распознавания

Comment: Вам необязательно обклеивать UI событиями логику. Если все завязано на изменение свойства, то и подписывайтесь на изменение свойства. `plotResult.PropertyChanged += (name) => { if (name == "CropImg") ВызватьТоЧтоДальшеДолжноПроизойти(); };` Если не соблюдать последовательность, точнее гарантию последовательности, то можете попасть в race condition, то есть ситуацию, когда участки кода выполняются в непредсказуемом порядке.

Comment: @aepot при таком подходе 
' plotResult.PropertyChanged += (name) ... ' нужно переписывать логику выбора элемента из списка, а мне пока это не хотелось делать. Что касается race condition, похоже что-то подобное и случилось

Comment: А если так `recognizer.RecognizeIt((Bitmap)fragmentPicBox.Image.Clone())`?

Comment: @aepot не помогло. Вся проблема с методом MouseUp, как я писал выше, при добавлении события **ListChanged (LC) c тестовым MessageBox**ом происходит: загрузка изображения (срабатывает LC) > выбираю прямоугольником > во втором PictureBoxе отрисовывается выбранная область (тут по идее должен был сработать LC, но его нет) > нажимаю Распознать > выводится текст (срабатывает LC) > закрываю тестовый MessageBox > Распознанный текст остается, но тут же удаляется картинка выделенного фрагмента. Кажется упускаю что-то простое, но не могу понять что именно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно моя проблема решается заменой
`DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` на `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation` в привязках.

```
originalPicBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", plotResults, "OriginalImg", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
fragmentPicBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Image", plotResults, "CropImg", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
recognRichTBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", plotResults, "RecognizedText", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Но мне по-прежнему непонятно почему при обновлении свойства **Image** контрола **fragmentPicBox** не происходит обновление свойства **CropImg** объекта *PlotResult*.

> *OnPropertyChanged* - Источник данных обновляется при каждом изменении
> свойства элемента управления.

> OnValidation  - Источник данных обновляется при проверке свойства элемента
> управления. После проверки значение свойства элемента управления также будет переформатировано.